# How to send an InputStream using POST request

Tags: java, python, android-studio, flask

I want to send a mp3 file using POST request from android studio to a flask server. I have read an mp3 file from device and stored in input stream object. The flask server identifies the request to be a POST request and creates the mp3 file. But when I play the mp3 file it does not work. So the connection part does not have any problem. I would like to know how to send this inputstream object in my POST request and get it successfully play the mp3 file on the server (Raspberry Pi).

The part to get the mp3 file and store in inputstream:

```
if(!DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, data.getData()))
    throw new RuntimeException("Not a documentsContract document");

try {
    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

    new Main4Activity.httpAsyncTask417().execute();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The part of sending the POST request:

```
public class httpAsyncTask417 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            String url="http://172.17.57.132/post_songs";
            URL obj=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            String urlParameters = "content=";

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.v("HTTPDelete_Check3", "Get returned: " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result

        }catch(java.io.IOException ex) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Below is the solution.

The part to get the mp3 file and store in inputstream:

```
    //if(!DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, data.getData()))
                    //    throw new RuntimeException("Not a documentsContract document");

                    try {
                        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                        uri=data.getData();
                        file_name=getFileName(uri);
                        new Main4Activity.httpAsyncTask417().execute();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The part of sending the POST request:

```
    try {
            String url="http://172.17.59.97/post_songs?title="+file_name;
            URL obj=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            /*BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                wr.writeBytes(line+'\n');
            }*/
            //wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + uri.toString() +"\"" + "\r\n");

            byte []buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read = 0;

            while ( (read = is.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
                wr.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.v("HTTPDelete_Check3", "Get returned: " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result

        }catch(java.io.IOException ex) {

        }
```